# IOS 8 issue with the UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, ios8

I have a label that represents a value. When the value changes the label updates correspondingly, however when running this on my iPhone 5C running iOS 8 there is a problem.

The label updates, but my entire view controller resets - all the sprites go back to their original positions and their attributes and properties are back the way they were when the app first started.

```
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value: %d", aValue];
```

I decided to run the application on the iPhone 4S simulator and then on an iOS 7 iPad and it worked just as expected.

I have tried many different methods for changing the label text and they all result in the same thing on my iOS 8 iPhone. This leads me to believe there is a problem with iOS 8.

Comment: I'm not convinced that that line is the problem. When you comment out that line, but still do EXACTLY the same thing, does this still happen?

Comment: If i comment that line out code works perfectly, it's everytime that label changes to different text that the storyboard's positions reset. Even if I use another method such as [scoreLabel setText] it still crashes, thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: Can you try setting the text to nothing?

Comment: Thanks for replying to me again, I tried setting the label text to nothing by using the following code:                                                                                        scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];                            It unfortunately does not help, I still get the same issue where the UIImageViews revert back to their storyboard positions when the label is set to different text.

Comment: When you JUST set the text to nothing, i.e., you only change that line to edit out the text, does it work? Don't set the text to something else afterwards; just set the text to nothing.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work

Comment: That's really strange. `scoreLabel.text = @"";` should definitly  not mess up with your controller.

Comment: Did I get it right: you 1) run app 2) manually change position of some elements 3) change some label's text 4) which results in autolayout, which returns all controls to their positions?

Comment: Yes @Lanorkin that is correct, everything just moves back to the positions that were set in the interface builder when I need the new positions I used in my .m file, please tell me you have some suggestions ?

Comment: @Zil Exactly, stil not working with iOS 8.1 BETA two and the new Xcode ... I'm not sure if its a coding error or just an iOS 8 error... runs fine on my ipad with iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I created my label in my storyboard but I was editing the position in my implementation file.

I solved the problem by deleting the label and re-creating it in code instead of using the storyboard, works well now.

Think it had something to do with the storyboard updating and re-arranging things due to the constraints, not sure though, if anyone else has this problem feel free to message me and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: I had the same exact bug, could not figure it out for hours. Still can't find the reason. I guess the constraints that the storyboard puts on have something to do with it. Anyways thanks for the answer it helped a lot.

Comment: @Cyprian Yeah, create the label out in your class, I think the constraints from he storyboard is going against the set position or something